# Query a NTP server using C# won't respond

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, ntp

While trying to receive the datetime from a NTP server using the following source code, I get the problem that from my home I can query the server but when I'm at work the flow stops at: s.Receive(ntpData);

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt = NtpClient.GetNetworkTime();
    }
}

public class NtpClient
{

    public static DateTime GetNetworkTime()
    {
        return GetNetworkTime("time-a.nist.gov");
    }

    public static DateTime GetNetworkTime(string ntpServer)
    {
        IPAddress[] address = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList;

        if (address == null || address.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Couldn not resolve Time Server " + ntpServer + "." , "ntpServer");
        }

        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(address[0], 123);

        return GetNetworkTime(ep);
    }

    public static DateTime GetNetworkTime(EndPoint ep)
    {
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        s.Connect(ep);

        byte[] ntpData = new byte[48]; // RFC 2030 
        ntpData[0] = 0x1B;
        for (int i = 1; i < 48; i++)
            ntpData[i] = 0;

        s.Send(ntpData);
        s.Receive(ntpData);

        byte offsetTransmitTime = 40;
        ulong intpart = 0;
        ulong fractpart = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            intpart = 256 * intpart + ntpData[offsetTransmitTime + i];

        for (int i = 4; i <= 7; i++)
            fractpart = 256 * fractpart + ntpData[offsetTransmitTime + i];

        ulong milliseconds = (intpart * 1000 + (fractpart * 1000) / 0x100000000L);
        s.Close();

        TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)milliseconds * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);

        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        dateTime += timeSpan;

        TimeSpan offsetAmount = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(dateTime);
        DateTime networkDateTime = (dateTime + offsetAmount);

        return networkDateTime;
    }
}
```

For me this smells like a firewall/network problem, any ideas?

Comment: Does this work with an off-the-shelf NTP client?

Comment: Do you mean off-the-shelf Windows NTP client? Or off-the-shelf framework NTP client?

Comment: Preferably just a regular Windows NTP client. The idea is to isolate the problem. Is it your app or something unique to your environment (like a firewall config problem). If it's the latter, then you have an IT issue.

Comment: I tried using a NTP client (http://www.bocan.ro/sntpclient) and got this error: ERROR: Timeout whilst trying to connect to time-a.nist.gov.

Comment: It sounds like it's a network problem, not a problem in your program.